# Views exposed filters without "Apply" button

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view with exposed filters of term select list. How can I make the select list to work directly on selecting an item, instead of clicking on the "Apply" button?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under advanced portion of view choose following

```
**Exposed form**

 Exposed form style: Basic | Settings
```

Then Choose autosubmit in Settings as shown below

[image]

This will hide the Apply button and the select list to work directly on selecting an item, instead of clicking on the Apply button.

Comment: I just configured as mentioned above, but now the filter is invisible. I use Views: 7.x-3.5 and BEF: 7.x-3.0-beta3

Comment: you mean exposed filter? please recheck. The above solution works here properly

Comment: Yes, exposed filter is invisible

Comment: I think you enable Exposed form in block: Yes, and it moved to blocks. in your case you can disable this option to Exposed form in block: No. Please try and let me know

Comment: I got the problem, actually I am trying to do that on page view so the exposed filter is not appearing

Comment: change Exposed form in block: to No

Comment: The good part is, I am able to disable the 'Apply' button without using the 'Better Exposed Filters' module. By selecting the Autosubmit option under Exposed form style:Basic | Settings. All this works on block view

Comment: yes it is available without better exposed filter also. i updated the answer

Comment: views exposed filters started working on page again, after removing and re-adding them again.

Comment: Thanks  Anoop Joseph, Actually it all works without using 'Better Exposed Filters' module.

Comment: yeah...:) i edited answer

Comment: Is there a solution for this problem in drupal 8? There doesn't seem to be an autosubmit checkbox and a hide submit button checkbox. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 8/9, You need the following module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autosubmit

Comment: thank you! You da man

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Drupal 8**. Choose **Exposed form style** as **Autosubmit** and then in **Settings** check Hide **submit button checkbox**.

[image]