# How to use AJAX for an exposed filter form of a Views block?

Tags: blocks, ajax, views

I have a View, in a block, assigned to a region. I have enabled Ajax for the view.  Pagination works with Ajax. Exposed filters do not. Exposed filters "submit".

I am definitely willing to cut corners at this point, so if there's a method that can be done with a simple JS function I will do that.

I believe that the problem is related to using the exposed form as a block. When "exposed form in block" is set to "no" ajax filtering does work.

update/solved:
I disable "exposed form in block" which I was using to change the position the filters. I then edited the view's template to get the position where I wanted it. so this is "solved" but I am not sure why it didn't work before.

Comment: No problems [here](https://rr4dv.ply.st/) maybe you have some JS that is causing a conflict? Check your browser's console for js errors.

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

You must install the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module:

> What else can I do with BEF?
>
> - Add help text for each exposed filter
> - Tame long lists with scrollable checkbox/radio button lists or select all/none links
> - ***Provide instant feedback by updating the View using AJAX whenever an exposed filter is changed***
> - Use the jQuery Slider widget for greater-than, less-than or in-between types of filters

You can read more about this in [Views exposed filters without "Apply" button](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/65585/28275)

Answer (score 3):

Exposed form as a block doesn't work out of the box with a block view.

There is an add-on module that does allow this configuration: [Views Block Exposed Filter Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_filter_block)

Comment: You saved my life thx!!